# NPM is known not to run on Node.js v11.15.0 I am working on angular js so cant lower version? what to do?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, npm-install

npm is known not to run on Node.js **

> v11.15.0V

**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Install nvm(Node Version Manager) with npm and manage nodejs version with it.

[Here is the link to know more about nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: I tried it so in that I have to reduce npm version too?

Comment: No you don't need to reduce npm's version. I'd suggest to install the latest version of NPM